# Duplicate Role Names on Asp.Net Identity and Multi-tenancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, asp.net-identity-2

I'm developing a Multi-tenancy web application with ASP.Net MVC and Identity 2.0. I have extended the IdentityRole like this:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }

    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

This because each Tenant will have individual sets of roles, like "Admin", "Staff", etc.

But the problem is, when I add a new Role, if the "Tenant A" has "Admin" role, when I add to "Tenant B" the "Admin" role, I get an IdentityResult error because "Admin" name is taken... Its is kinda obvious because the "Name" field on the AspNetRoles table is Unique...

```
IdentityResult roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(
  new ApplicationRole
  {
    Name = "Admin",
    TenantId = GetTenantId()
  });
```

But then how I can customize ASP.Net Identity so the "Name" field in the "AspNetRoles" can be unique with "TenantId", and not alone? I found info about extend the IdentityRole (like I did adding a field), but not about change it or replace it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply alter database's schema on `ApplicationDbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var role = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
        .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    role.Property(r => r.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(256)
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") 
            { IsUnique = false }));
}
```

But you must customize `RoleValidator` class also. Because default role validator invalidates duplicated role names.

```
public class MyRoleValidator:RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>
{
     public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(ApplicationRole item)
     {
         // implement your validation logic here

         return IdentityResult.Success;
     }
}
```

Now every time you create the role manager you must set the role validator.

```
roleManager.RoleValidator=new MyRoleValidator();
```

Comment: Sam, when I try your solution, the add-migration command raises this error:
Conflicting configuration settings were specified for column 'Name' on table 'IdentityRole': Index attribute property 'IsUnique' = 'False' conflicts with index attribute property 'IsUnique' = 'True'

Comment: But after that its throwing exception: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: @ClickOk how did you solve this? You say that it throws error but you marked this solution as accepted, did it really work?

Comment: @ibubi, sorry, I cant remember, this answer was ~3 years ago for an older project. But this message was edited after my comment, so probably this edit fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a composite unique constraint on both RoleName and TenantId, but first, the unique constraint of the role name must be removed here is the code:

```
 public class ApplicationRoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationRole> builder)
    {
        //remove the current idenx
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.NormalizedName).IsUnique(false);
        // add composite constraint 
        builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.NormalizedName, x.TenantId }).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

then the role validator must be overridden to check the uniqueness of both role name and TenantId:

```
public class TenantRoleValidator : RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>
{
    private IdentityErrorDescriber Describer { get; set; }

    public TenantRoleValidator() : base()
    {

    }
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> manager, ApplicationRole role)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
        }
        if (role == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));
        }
        var errors = new List<IdentityError>();
        await ValidateRoleName(manager, role, errors);
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());
        }
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
    private async Task ValidateRoleName(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> manager, ApplicationRole role,
    ICollection<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        var roleName = await manager.GetRoleNameAsync(role);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleName))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidRoleName(roleName));
        }
        else
        {
            var owner = await manager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
            if (owner != null
                && owner.TenantId == role.TenantId
                && !string.Equals(await manager.GetRoleIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetRoleIdAsync(role)))
            {
                errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateRoleName(roleName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, register the new Role validator:

```
        services
          .AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
          .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
          .AddRoleValidator<TenantRoleValidator>()
```

Don't forget to migrate the changes to the database before running the code

Comment: This was a complete answer with all parts clearly explained. Thanks.

Comment: thank you but,builder.HasIndex(x => x.NormalizedName).IsUnique(false);
did not change any thing in migration do you now why?

Comment: could you explain me why this did not work with me 
here is my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75790740/cant-drop-unique-index-over-normalizedname-using-identity-ef-core

Comment: When adding your validator, don't forget to remove the default RoleValidator because validators are accumulated (not replaced) by default (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46066). After registering your validator, add this: `var defaultRoleValidator = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ImplementationType == typeof(RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>));
if (defaultRoleValidator != null)
{
    services.Remove(defaultRoleValidator);
}`

Comment: The _ApplicationRoleConfiguration_ class could be avoided if you don't have the _NormalizedName_ index (it's my case).

Comment: The _TenantRoleValidator_ class contructor must includes _IdentityErrorDescriber_: `public TenantRoleValidator(IdentityErrorDescriber? errors = null) : base(errors)
    {
        Describer = errors ?? new IdentityErrorDescriber();
    }`

Comment: It's also important to know that the default implementation for the _UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>_ class  (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/19e6bdb2df4f96b9ab2e1f1596a08ec258eab8dd/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs) when using _AddRoles_ (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46593#issuecomment-1429734979), add claims to the identity based on role name, not role id. This causes the **claims to be loaded from the first role with the name of the user's role**, which can belong to another tenant (depending on the order of the roles table).

Answer (score 0):

There's another *check for uniqueness of role name* in [`IdentityDbContext.ValidateEntity()`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs#L429-L434) which must be overriden too.