# Can't drop unique index over NormalizedName using identity ef core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make the role unique per `NormalizedName` and other properties

I'm using asp .net core 3.1
What I'm trying is to drop the unique index over `NormalizedName` and make it over multiple properties

that is my dbContext

```
ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
```

and this is my inject

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {

                options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = providerName;
                options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = providerName;
                options.Tokens.ChangeEmailTokenProvider = providerName;
                options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider;
            })
                .AddRoleValidator<TenantRoleValidator>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddTokenProvider<CustomTotpTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>(providerName);
```

my `ApplicationRole` inherit from `IdentityRole`
what i try

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationRole> builder)
        {
            builder.HasIndex(c => c.NormalizedName).IsUnique(false);
            builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.NormalizedName, c.SupplierId, c.CustomerId }).IsUnique(true);
        }
```

but unfortunately after `Add-Migration` by the reslt was

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoles_NormalizedName_SupplierId_CustomerId",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: new[] { "NormalizedName", "SupplierId", "CustomerId" },
                unique: true);
```

What I expected was for him to update the index over `NormalizedName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this removes index

```
var index = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
            .HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedName }).Metadata;
            var applicationUserType = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().Metadata.RemoveIndex(index.Properties);
```

This should be done after calling `base.OnModelCreating()` to avoid it being recreated

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6239) issue on github?

Comment: Always good to provide a summary of what you're linking to instead of minimal information and a link for someone to follow. The aim is to have as much information on this site as possible